# Turn int 12345 into float 1.2345 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I want to turn 12345 into 1.2345

This with different numbers.

Here is what I've done so far, and it works, it's just not very pretty, and seems like a hack.

```
var number = 12345
> 12345
var numLength = number.toString().length
> 5
var str = number +'e-' + (numLength - 1)
> "12345e-4"
var float = parseFloat(str)
> 1.2345
```

Is there something that just my decimal point back 4 places?

I tried

```
Math.pow(number, -4)
> 4.3056192580926564e-17
```

and it doesn't come up with what I need even slightly.

`Math.exp()` only takes one argument(the exponent) and applies it to Eulers constant. `Returns Ex, where x is the argument, and E is Euler's constant (2.718…), the base of the natural logarithm.`

Dividing by `10000` won't work as number isn't always going to be just `12345`. it might be `123` or `1234234614`. In both cases I still need `1.23` or `1.234234614`

Comment: Have you considered dividing by 10000?

Comment: @RaymondChen Hoare's Law. :-)

Comment: @RaymondChen Of course. But It's not consistantly 10000. the query might be 123, and dividing by 10000 wouldn't work. I need to divide by 100 at that point.

Comment: regex solution for the fun `var f=function(x, n){var r = x.match(/^(-?\d)(\d+)(.\d+)?$/), dec=r[2]+(r[3]?r[3].slice(1):''); if(n!==undefined)dec=dec.slice(0,n); return r[1]+'.'+dec+'e'+r[2].length}`  `f('-12345.678', 2) = "-1.23e4"`

Comment: @crl Well that definitely is fun. :)

Comment: As you phrased your question, you said you wanted to move the decimal point four places. Dividing by 10000 does that. Now you changed it so you want to divide by whatever it takes so there is one digit before the decimal point. In the future, please be clearer what you are asking for.

Comment: Thank you @RaymondChen Your answer is why I edited my question to include not just moving the decimal point.

Comment: You never did say that what you want to do is to divide by powers of two until the result has one digit before the decimal point. You just gave examples and hoped we could figure out what you wanted. (`123` becomes `1.23` and `1234234614` becomes `1.234234614`). In the future, state what you want. Often, you'll find that a clear statement of what you want will also tell you what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getBase10Mantissa(input) {
  // Make sure we're working with a number.
  var source = parseFloat(input);
  // Get an integer for the base-10 log for the source value (round down in case of 
  // negative result).
  var exponent = Math.floor(Math.log10(source));
  // Raise 10 to the power of exponent and divide the source value by that.
  var mantissa = source / Math.pow(10, exponent);
  // Return mantissa only (per request).
  return mantissa;
}
```

Comment: @BrianNoah Sure. You can do that. I was being thorough enough that you would have both pieces if you needed them.

Comment: FYI, I'm doing this in node.js which has removed log10(or just hasn't added it in) and I have to do `Math.log(number) / Math.log(10)` in order to get log10

Comment: @BrianNoah Elegant solution to a deficiency in the library. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
function f(n){
    return n/(Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(n))));
}
```

You need to divide n by 10^x, where x is how "long" the number is. Turns out the length of the number is just the floor of the logarithm of the number.

Comment: perfect. a+ for simplicity.